# Best first steps for a hard drive?

Tags: windows, security, bootloader, disk-encryption

I volunteer my time to service my schoolmates, fixing their problems, but conversations have come up about surveillance and hacking.

I've been watching DEFCON's videos, and have learned that even flashing the BIOS, a clean OS, and disk encryption is not secure. There are more steps that can be even more useful. I'm looking for some opinions, in step order, as to what one should do for super security. Once I learn this, I intend on employing this for as many people as possible.

I have come across things such as encrypting RAM and TPMs, but does anyone have any advice on what the best setup for heavy duty secure systems to prevent bypassing anything?

Almost everyone I help is using Windows (which is why they manage to get viruses), but I would think that as long as the boot process to disk encryption is all secure, their computers will still be secure, so they can continue to use Windows safely. There are some people who have expressed willingness to change to Linux, but I can't convince everyone.

I hope that was all coherent - I'm really tired. Again, I'm wondering what the steps to take are for pretty much the most secure start-to-finish boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is essentially a bit like the old "how can I protect my virtual assets so noone may copy them?".

The short answer: You can't.

The big question is: **Why would you want super secure encryption?**

In non-corporate environments, there's typically no reason to, unless you plan to do shady things, and even then it's questionable.

If you've got something extra sensitive that may not be compromised in any situation, don't store it in the first place. If it isn't there, noone will be able to access/steal/modify it.

Judging from your question, it sounds a bit like you want encryption to protect a system from malware. That simply won't work.

Disk encryption (e.g. through a TPM) works on a very low level. It will prevent access to data without proper credentials. However, to allow programs on the actual encrypted disk to run or access that data, the system will encrypt/decrypt the contents on the fly.

This won't keep any malware from copying or listing anything that's on there and it won't keep any malware from copying/installing its files.

It will however, avoid someone being able to access those files using something such as a live CD (assuming they don't have proper credentials and the actual TPM).

Also in theory Unix systems are as insecure as Windows systems. You'll just have to find the actual issues or exploits. Take [Shellshock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellshock_(software_bug)) and [Heatbleed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartbleed) as two very recent and very popular examples. These weren't fixed to Windows at all.

Due to this Unix (or any other non-Windows) isn't some magical "protects them all" solution. Windows can be as secure as Unix, MacOS X, or any other OS. The big important part (and most likely security hole) is the actual user.

Also adding stuff like memory encryption, hardware encryption, etc. will also cause additional overhead, potentially slowing down systems significantly.

As such I'd advice you to **not** delude your friends by any potentially false claims or promises on "cyber security" just by enabling hardware encryption or installing some other operating system you consider more secure or less likely to be infected (**no** system is 100% secure against intrusions unless really locked/gated, but even old consoles without networking got "hacked" in some way).

Instead, let them use the system of their choice, but use your own knowledge to:

a) Help them installing a recent version (e.g. avoid Windows XP) as well as all security relevant updates.

b) Install basic protection (like a antivirus or malware scanner unless already bundled by default). While this isn't a 100% foolproof solution either, it can help, especially with people less tech-savy.

c) Teach them how to browse the web or use email in a more secure way (e.g. by starting not to click any misleading banners, downloading or installing programs from strangers, opening mail attachments, etc.).

d) Tell them how/if/when their data might be (ab)used (e.g. filling forms on the web, phishing, etc.).

Comment: Nice answer - though, if you just want to keep your parents out, just password it :P

Comment: @Steven: I already thought that most systems are already infected ins some way etc. but what I've tried to say was that just by adding some encryption layer those computers won't become invulnerable or less vulnerable. If you download adware or spyware, it will run and won't care whether the system is actually encrypted or not (the OS will happily encrypt/decrypt things on the fly for it just like for any other program). Using an incompatible system (e.g. some Unix or Linux to avoid Windows malware) might be a step in the right direction, but only if they're able to use that system properly.